# Mac Automator App: How to Set Folder

Tags: macos, arguments, applescript, automator

This is probably something simple but its driving me crazy...

I was just able to build my first automator workflow, which is quite basic and uses the Subtitles application to download subtitles for movies in a specific folder.

The Actions are:

Get Folder Contents
Filter Finder Items (to only movie files)
Open finder item with the Subtitle app

It works fine when I execute the workflow from within Automator because it has a "Folder Action receives files and folders added to:" clause in the beginning which tells which folder to use.

However, I want to save that as an application so I can schedule that on iCal but, when I save as an app, the clause which tells the folder is no longer available and looks like I need to pass the folder name as a parameter/argument and I have no idea on how to do that.

So, what I need guidance is on how to have the app executed in iCal while telling it which folder to use.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Apoligies. I was not aware of the existence of "http://apple.stackexchange.com" which I think is better suited for this question I just posted it there. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a "run applescript" action above your "Get Folder Contents" action. Make the applescript code look like the following. Make sure to put your folder path between the quotes.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    return "/Users/username/Desktop/"
end run
```

Note: a quick way to get a path is to run this in Script Editor and use the result.

```
return POSIX path of (choose folder)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot regulus6633. That did not resolved the issue though... It still runs fine from within Automator but when I execute the app directly by double clicking on it i get a "The action Open Finder Items encountered an error" which is actually the same message I get if I put a "Get Specified Finder Items" action in order to set the folder... The app actually runs after that message but does not processes all files on the folder. I am trying to troubleshoot that (removed subfolders and will try to narrow the files) but any other help would be appreciated... Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok. Did some testing and it looks like the issue is actually related to the "Filter Finder Items" action. Whenever the results are more than 2 different types of files, i get the "The action Open Finder Items encountered an error" message. 

I was using 2 filter expressions on the filter action. Extension is mp4 or extension = mkv. This always resulted on the error. But when I use only one expression (filer only one file) it works fine.

I now have one app to process mkv files  and another to process mp4 files and this is working. But I would still like to use one single app for that... hints?